# Accessing elements inside HTML using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, json, function, accordion

I'm trying to access elements inside an accordion menu. I populate my accordion menu with JSON data which is loaded using jQuery. I can see that the full menu is being created when the page loads. The problem is that I can't access the second level in the menu.

JSON-file ("cwdata.json"):

```
{
    "Country": [{
            "CountryName": "COUNTRY NAME GOES HERE",
            "Region": [{
                    "RegionName": "REGION NAME GOES HERE",
                    "SubRegion": [{
                            "SubRegionName": "SUBREGION NAME GOES HERE"
                        }]
                }]
        }]
}
```

jQuery used to populate the accordion menu from a JSON file:

```
$.getJSON('../JSON/cwdata.json', function (cwData) {
        $.each(cwData.Country, function (i, country) { // loop through all the countries
            var countries = '<li class="country_name"><a href="#">' + country.CountryName + '</a></li>'; // the name of the country
            var country_region = '<ul class="country_region">'; // create a list of all the regions in the country
            var region_subregion = "";

            $.each(country.Region, function (i, region) { // loop through all the regions
                country_region += '<li class="region_name"><a href="#">' + region.RegionName + '</a></li>'; // the name of the region
                region_subregion = '<ul class="region_subregion">'; // create a list of all the subregions in the region

                $.each(region.SubRegion, function (i, subregion) { // loop through all the regions
                    region_subregion += '<li class="subregion_name"><a href="#">' + subregion.SubRegionName + '</a></li>'; // the name of the subregion
                });
                region_subregion += '</u>'; //close the list tags
            });
            country_region += '</ul>'; //close the list tags
            $(countries).appendTo('#Country').append(country_region); // append the region to the country and append the country to the accorion menu
            $(region_subregion).appendTo("li.region_name"); // append the subregion to the region
        });
    }); // getJSON
```

The first item in the menu ("Home") works when I click on it. But any item under "Home" has no reaction or feedback when I click on it.

This is the HTML menu after the page has been loaded:

[image]

I can use this code to check what the element is when I click on it:

```
$("a").click(function (event) {
    alert("Value: " + event.target);
});
```

If I click on "Home", it returns: `"Value: HTMLSpanElement"`. But when I click on "COUNTRY NAME GOES HERE", nothing happens. I couldn't get this to work on a Fiddle either but here is what I can supply:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/3d6Nz/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle doesn't work at all. I think you're getting a jQuery error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Make sure your jQuery references are called before the script.

Comment: in jsfiddle you have to select jquery library on the left panel first.

Answer (score 0):

That is because, you are calling click event function before getJSON completed probably. Use following structure;

```
var $result = $.getJSON('../JSON/cwdata.json', function(cwData){
    ......
});

$result.done(function(){
    $("a").click(function (event) {
      alert("Value: " + event.target);
    });
});
```

For more detail about `.done`, refer [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) and search title **The jqXHR Object**

Answer (score 0):

changed your code to works traversing the local json data and testing that the clicks indeed work.

Adapted your function to run only when the page has the document loaded

FOLLOWS THE FIDDLE: [CLICK HERE (Updated)](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3d6Nz/19/)

UPDATE: To be possible to use a valid external URL JSON file I had to change the data from JSON to JSONP approach and the data file changed to that:

```
Populate({
    "Country": [{
        "CountryName": "COUNTRY NAME GOES HERE",
        "Url" : "http://country",
        "Region": [{
                "RegionName": "REGION NAME GOES HERE",
                "Url" : "http://region",
                "SubRegion": [{
                        "SubRegionName": "SUBREGION NAME GOES HERE",
                        "Url" : "http://subregion"
                    }]
            }]
    }]
});
```

Also updated the rotine to use the URL properties from JSON to apply in the anchor elements

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({ url:'http://rkti.com/stack/data.js', dataType: 'jsonp'});

});
```

Placed the main logic in a named `Populate` function to be called by the JSONP onsuccess-load.

```
function Populate(cwData) {

    $.each(cwData.Country, function (i, country) {
        var countries = '<li class="country_name"><a href="' + country.Url + '">' + country.CountryName + '</a></li>';
        var country_region = '<ul class="country_region">';
        var region_subregion = "";

        $.each(country.Region, function (i, region) {
            country_region += '<li class="region_name"><a href="' + region.Url + '">' + region.RegionName + '</a></li>';
            region_subregion = '<ul class="region_subregion">';

            $.each(region.SubRegion, function (i, subregion) {
                region_subregion += '<li class="subregion_name"><a href="' + subregion.Url + '">' + subregion.SubRegionName + '</a></li>';
            });
            region_subregion += '</u>';
        });
        country_region += '</ul>';
        $(countries).appendTo('#Country').append(country_region);
        $(region_subregion).appendTo("li.region_name");
    });

    $('a').on('click',function(e){
        alert($(this).text());
        e.preventDefault(); //Avoids default behavior of A# (going to top/change page)
        e.stopPropagation(); //Avoits any recursive click
    });   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort on the (working) Fiddle. I see now that the problem actually lies where I load my JSON from a file. When I put the JSON inside my JavaScript it works as it should. But when I load it from a file it gives me the 'no response' effect.

Comment: When I click on "COUNTRY NAME GOES HERE"-item (when the JSON is retrieved from the file) the url changes to `http://localhost:10659/#`. BUT, when I click on "COUNTRY NAME GOES HERE"-item (when the JSON is inside the JavaScript file) the url does not change at all.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. First you have to inform a valid URL as the source of your json (You are informing a File Path, thats not an URL).

Comment: Second, you have to change the url attribute of the "a" element in the HTML construction, im going to update the fiddle with those...

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by unbound event handlers. As stated before, you could attach the event handlers after the nodes are inserted in the DOM tree. But this could cause the creation many event handler functions. To prevent that, you could use event delegation:

```
$("#options").on('click', 'a', function (event) {
    $el = $(this);
    alert($el.text());  
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();       
});
```

This alerts all link texts.

And yes, your jsFiddle is broken, you forgot to enable jQuery support.

Answer (score 0):

Since your list is dynamically generated you need to use on(), click() only works on items already on the page like your "Home" link:

```
$("a").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevent default browser behavior
    alert("Value: " + $(this).text()); //Wrap "this" with jQuery to access the clicked element
});
```